# Count in update query doesn't work in Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

```
public function increment($id)
{
    $this->model->where("id",'=', $id)->update(['rating'=> DB::raw('count+1')]);
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'count' in
>   'field list' (SQL: update `news` set `rating` = count+1, `updated_at`
>   = 2019-04-13 08:12:51 where `id` = 5)

I also tried

```
->update(['rating'=>'count+1']);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not telling the query builder on which table you are performing the query, so `DB::raw('count+1')` makes no sense.

You can try to use the eloquent increment method like this:

```
$this->model->where("id", $id)->increment('rating');
```

Thanks @Tharaka removed the extra call to save().

Comment: hah i tried it last time but i made  stupid mistake, thank you for this, it work. But in last line must be update(). Thanks

Comment: and, you don't have to call `save()`. it automatically saves to the database.